# rsync exclude config.js but include lib/project/config.js

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a folder like this

```
/
  config.js
  /lib
    /project
      config.js
```

In the root directory I execute rsync

```
rsync -azvr --exclude config.js --include lib/project/config.js  .  dest
```

The `/lib/project/config.js` is not sync to the dest, how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need reorder you `include/exclude` parameter become

```
# rsync -azvr --include lib/project/config.js --exclude config.js . dest
sending incremental file list
./
lib/
lib/project/
lib/project/config.js
```

Instead

```
# rsync -azvr --exclude config.js --include lib/project/config.js . dest
sending incremental file list
./
lib/
lib/project/

sent 73 bytes  received 23 bytes  192.00 bytes/sec
```